# xhr uploadProgress not called in IE8

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, xmlhttprequest, jquery.form.js

I use jQuery form plugin(jquery.form.js) in my project. It works fine in Chrome/FF, but in IE8/9, the uploadProgress callback not called. Even the demo in the official web site http://jquery.malsup.com/form/progress.html doesn't update upload progress in IE8/9.Or how to achieve upload progress function?Thanks

Comment: XMLHttpRequest2 is not supported in IE before version 10 - 7,8 and 9 use so called `XMLHttpRequest 1` - see [compatibility table](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest#Browser_compatibility)

Comment: Then how can I implement the upload progress, brother?

Comment: Short answer: you can't. Long answer: look at old Internet Exploder ActiveX methods of AJAX ... `new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");` ... perhaps that can help, I don't know, all my web sites redirect Internet Exploder users to http://info.cern.ch/hypertext/WWW/TheProject.html :p

Comment: Yes, is there any way to replace upload progress or other compatible low version IE, other uploading methods have better demo, thanks a lot

Comment: Should be for xhr.upload not supported